# HttpException in Handler.php line 107: This action is unauthorized

Tags: laravel-5, policy, authorize

I'm learning Laravel 5. I have finished the document's [Quickstart - intermediate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate). I want to apply the authorize check for Task's actions to the User's. I want to check whether the target user is the current logged in user in order to use user's edit action. However, browser keeps telling me when I try to access `http://myfirst.app/users/2/edit`:

```
FatalThrowableError in UsersPolicy.php line 20:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Policies\UsersPolicy::edit() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of App\User given
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', 'UsersController@view');
Route::get('/users/{user}/edit', 'UsersController@edit');
Route::patch('/users/{user}', 'UsersController@update');
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    'App\Task' => 'App\Policies\TaskPolicy',
    'App\User' => 'App\Policies\UsersPolicy',
];
```

UsersPolicy.php

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UsersPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function edit(Request  $request, User $user)
    {
        return $request->user()->id === $user->id;
    }

    public function update(Request  $request, User $user)
    {
        return $request->user()->id === $user->id;
    }
}
```

UsersController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

    protected $user;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function view(Request $request, User $user)
    {    
        if($request->user()->id == $user->id){
            return view('users.view', ['user' => $user]);
        }
        return redirect('/tasks');
    }

    public function edit(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('edit', $user);
        return view('users.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $user);        
        $user->update($request->all());    
        return redirect('/users/'.$user->id);
    }
}
```

In the [Document's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#route-model-binding) TaskController's delete function, `$user` isn't passed into `$this->authorized('destroy', $task)` in order to allow TaskPolicy's destroy function to use `$user`:

TaskController.php

```
public function destroy(Task $task)
{
    $this->authorize('destroy', $task);
    $task->delete();
    return redirect('/tasks');

}
```

TaskPolicy.php

```
public function destroy(User $user, Task $task)
{
    return $user->id === $task->user_id;
}
```

Anyway, I followed the exception and added $request to UsersController's edit function's parameter

```
$this->authorize('edit', $request, $user);
```

And I get

```
HttpException in Handler.php line 107:
This action is unauthorized.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

In your Request file set

```
  public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in UsersPolicy.php add:

```
enter code here/**
 * @var User
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * Create a new policy instance.
 *
 * @param User $user
 */
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

And in your UsersController.php change `$this->authorize('edit', $user);` to `$this->authorize('edit');`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

as per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization): "The Gate will automatically return  false for all abilities when there is not an authenticated user".  So before doing any authorization, please check Auth::user() if it returns a currently authenticated user.